# Retrieve value from onClick Listenener

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have `RecyclerView` in my project and I am displaying all items using this `RecyclerView`. My question here is how to store the name that I clicked in my `RecyclerView` item. Code is working fine and any help will be appreciated.

**Code**

```
class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bindItem (test : TestModel) {
        var testName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TestName)
        testName.text = test.TestName

        itemView.setOnClickListener { 
            val intent = Intent(itemView.context, Test:: class.java)
            itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getAdapterPosition()` is what you are looking for . it will give you position of clicked item then you can get data from your dataset for this position .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

current form

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
{

    fun bindItem(Test:TestModel)
    {
       var TestName:TextView=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.TestName)
        TestName.text=Test.TestName

        itemView.setOnClickListener {

            val intent= Intent(itemView.context, Test::class.java)
             intent.putExtra("name",TestName.Text.toString())
            itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
                                     }
    }
}
```

to the form want to go is

```
var testName:String=intent.getStringExtra("name")
```

or for java:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getExtraString("name")
```

Comment: Thanks @jhayjhay for your code. I have modified the code as per kotlin syntax. Above code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can textView.setTag(xx),and getTag() in onClickListener

Comment: Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: where do you want to store the name

Comment: I need to pass the name that is clicked to next class.